# Cannot display full string in emacs

Tags: doom

I have doomemacs installed freshly, without any customization, and I found my emacs hides part of the string from being displayed in `emacs-lisp-mode`. E.g., the following line:

```
(package! org-roam-ui :recipe (:host github :repo "org-roam/org-roam-ui" :files ("*.el" "out")))
```

is been displayed as:

```
(package! org-roam-ui :recipe (:host github :repo "org-roam/org..." :files ("*.el" "out")))
```

the `org-roam-ui` is displayed as `org...`, Why is that and how I bring the full string display back?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’ve left out any information about what you did to arrive at this problem, so I will have to use my psychic debugging powers and guess. If you had just typed this into a source buffer then this probably wouldn’t have happened, so you must have evaluated some code and this is the result of that evaluation.

In that case, the variables `eval-expression-print-length` and `eval-expression-print-level` control how expressions are abbreviated. As [chapter 27.9 Evaluating Emacs Lisp Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Eval.html) of the Emacs manual says:

```
   The options ‘eval-expression-print-level’ and
‘eval-expression-print-length’ control the maximum depth and length of
lists to print in the result of the evaluation commands before
abbreviating them.  Supplying a zero prefix argument to
‘eval-expression’ or ‘eval-last-sexp’ causes lists to be printed in 
full.
```

You can read the manual inside of Emacs by typing `C-h i`, then selecting the Emacs manual from the list.